# Displaying a 3D model in JavaScript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, webgl

I am looking at rendering a 3D model in a browser. What tools should I use/what places should I look at?

I don't know what data format the model will be, I can likely request that data to formatted in any way I want.

I am looking at [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) but it seems that it needs WebGL to work, which appears to be unsupported in IE.

Does a "cross-browser compatible HTML 3d rendering engine" exists? :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have not played with 3D yet, but I know a good place for ressources on 3D for HTML5.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/gaming

And here is a tutorial on how to create your 3D models with the `Three.js` Framework.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/three/intro/

This may help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

I also needed what you've been searching for and did some research.

I found **JSC3D** (https://code.google.com/p/jsc3d/). 
It's a project written entirely in Javascript and uses the HTML canvas. It has been tested for Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE9 and more.

Then you have services as **p3d.in** and **Sketchfab** that give you a nice reader to view 3D models on a web page: they use HTML5 and WebGL. They both have a free version.

Answer (score 4):

a couple years down the road, I'd vote for three.js because

ie 11 supports webgl (to what extent I can't assure you since i'm usually in chrome)

and, as far as importing external models into three.js, here's a link to mrdoob's updated loaders (so many!)

UPDATE nov 2019: the THREE.js loaders are now far more and it makes little sense to post them all: just go to this link

http://threejs.org/examples
and review the loaders - at least 20 of them

Comment: Could you please provide sample code instead of posting a link

Comment: it seems redundant to repost what mrdoob has for source code examples, no?

Comment: link goes to 404 now so I guess redundancy might have been a good thing

Answer (score 3):

do you work with a 3d tool such as maya? for maya you can look at http://www.inka3d.com

Comment: Interesting. The 3D model is not in fact coming from a modeling software like Maya, but from a topographical scanner. Having said that, I can probably output the data into a format inka understands.