# Creating dynamic simple 3d model and updating in web browser

Tags: java, php, javascript, flash, actionscript

I curently have a website with many users and on one of its page I need to create a visual represanmtation of data in 3d model. This 3d model should be easy to update depending on the data provided from database for that perticular user. (for example, it is going to be a square board and a ball on it and the ball position is detemined depending on the data given from datatbase).

I am currently confused about which technology/langauge to use for this that will make this task easy.

I have thought about using Java, JavaScript and flash (actionscript?).

Which of the above should be easiest to implement or if you know something other then the one in list above then please also suggest that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350090/displaying-a-3d-model-in-javascript-html5

Comment: cant speak for Java, but creating the 3d scene you describe in Flash would be relatively trivial with a 3d library such as away3d. Also trivial to change size/position of 3d objects within scene. Heres a starter tutorial to give you an idea of complexity: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/creating-games-away3d.html

Comment: ...of course, Flash is no good for mobile browsers, if that is a consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebGL, but you need a browser that support it. There are also library that helps you, like [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/), take a look to the demo.

Of course, if you need to support a larger set of browsers, the best solution is currently Flash; that has a good set of 3D APIs and – even if it's mostly for game – is supported by [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) too.

Comment: Thanks. using WebGL, is it possible to change a model slightly depending on data suplied in web browser?

Comment: Sure, you can basically do whatever you want. Not sure if it's related to your question, but take a look [here](http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/undulating-monkey/) for example.